# Swagger generated REST API docs showing query params as required (but I want not-required)

Tags: rest, swagger

I am generating swagger docs for my REST API. The generated docs show the params are **required**. How to make them **not-required** in swagger ? In actual REST invocations they are not-required (as expected); so problem is just in documentation.

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getBaz(
        @DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam("foo") final boolean myFoo,
        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("bar") final String myBar
) { ... }
```

The generated swagger.json has

```
... "parameters":[{   ... snip "myBar":"bar","required":true}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@ApiParam`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) annotation will do the trick. From the Swagger [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiparam):

> The `@ApiParam` is used solely with the JAX-RS parameter annotations (`@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, `@HeaderParam`, `@FormParam` and in JAX-RS 2, `@BeanParam`). While swagger-core scans these annotations by default, the `@ApiParam` can be used to add more details on the parameters or change the values as they are read from the code. [...]

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html), you can use [`required`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html#required()) to specify if the parameter is required or not. To use it, do as following:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response method(@ApiParam(value = "foo", required = false) @QueryParam("foo") boolean foo,
                       @ApiParam(value = "bar", required = false) @QueryParam("bar") String bar) { 
    ...
}
```

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed that looks like it SHOULD do exactly as I want, but in my test just now, it made no difference i.e. I still see "required":true in the generated swagger.json !

Comment: @k1eran What version are you using? The [current stable version is 1.5.4](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/releases). An issue with `@ApiParam` [was reported](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/937) in old versions.

Comment: It turns out that my project is using its own custom maven-plugin to generate the swagger.json files (somewhat similar to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/plugin/CodeGenMojo.java ) which unfortunately ignores the swagger-specific annotation @ApiParam and uses a different approach to detect that "required":true is needed. (I'm still not sure why my project has this approach; however as your advice is the correct solution for the "standard" swagger setup... thank you &  I am accepting your answer.